# Arduino secure webrequest certificate error

Tags: c, ssl, arduino, x509certificate

I am trying to execute code on my ESP32 based on this example:

https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFiClientSecure/examples/WiFiClientSecure/WiFiClientSecure.ino

My code extract

```
const char* root_ca = \
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"MIID3TCCAsWgAwIBAgIIStTO2/9KgZgwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwTzELMAkGA1UE\n" \
"BhMCREUxCzAJBgNVBAgTAkhFMRQwEgYDVQQKEwtLYWlzZXJTbWl0aDELMAkGA1UE\n" \
"CxMCQ0ExEDAOBgNVBAMTB0hvbWUtQ0EwIBcNMjMwNjEzMTgxOTAwWhgPMjA3MzA2\n" \
"MTMxODE5MDBaME8xCzAJBgNVBAYTAkRFMQswCQYDVQQIEwJIRTEUMBIGA1UEChML\n" \
"S2Fpc2VyU21pdGgxCzAJBgNVBAsTAkNBMRAwDgYDVQQDEwdIb21lLUNBMIIBIjAN\n" \
"BgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA8QvNdPHqOLeknPljyQZHemTpvH9Y\n" \
"dePyDs1ItzCjwQJA//BK/Kho3iWXnQuKWQ5C3av1qJYK4xR3iLRuZzzyiPEuC4Bg\n" \
"k6O2B+hAfeCy5RKSErzHveCZNCmYJw7HAGv+hoDqu8HEmerkT9Lag1ar0HCtBXvj\n" \
"VZQlzYEkfZvcG6ZSNnl7v5qHTnsI6KTd6OcnNJyFAwgt0hv/3kC/zob9EWq99aCK\n" \
"Yth3cufrq1oDrUREQvVm6kABRnrHwlcHChH3HWuCEyKX3Pf/Rm//cu0vyq87AY9y\n" \
"tHiuVltmufuqpbyFw2cF1DFEPaXFE4W5pwt1NMn550/QvO9qqiGI2kT2FQIDAQAB\n" \
"o4G6MIG3MA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFPOTzLHrzbQbde0QLD9z\n" \
"UXQ33klgMAsGA1UdDwQEAwIBBjBFBgNVHR8EPjA8MDqgOKA2hjRodHRwOi8vY3Js\n" \
"My5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vRGlnaUNlcnRBc3N1cmVkSURSb290Q0EuY3JsMBEGCWCG\n" \
"SAGG+EIBAQQEAwIABzAeBglghkgBhvhCAQ0EERYPeGNhIGNlcnRpZmljYXRlMA0G\n" \
"CSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQCOSdzCrY0+CUDFCLzqBQn5ZSoDDRWMROwd1mdPPJeT\n" \
"2hAEMzfYsRpH7zr4bOoIVOsIvM/RQWo2h40rWCjjzhVRxlrrIwrWNqte2T3tqJts\n" \
"PwWWy2tFt27i394arjFF+dIxWGvxFgF6P10QS+p9nB0G5oOOVNUa0NV19Kud/Zqa\n" \
"tNvqkYf+Q+rpn3onXXyQVydM1b/K08XdiSMN5m79us0LbmiYZ2kz9yOUrsCDUQPH\n" \
"MvrSAZRbh5JeZHbG60BHg4onii7UmCQsLZIbcybE5+V12btHIh8H/Q7o/e+TM3oI\n" \
"14KmsO31mJCdek6dgssycixPl76nOpEMrbGqh47zY68T\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";


 client.setCACert(root_ca);


 IPAddress host_ip = {192,168,178,61}; //Or if I use server hostname, the result is the same
 const int httpsPort = 8788;

  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  if (!client.connect(host_ip, httpsPort))
  {
    Serial.println("Connection failed!");
     char err_buf[1000];
    if (client.lastError(err_buf,1000)<0) {
          Serial.print("Last WiFiClientSecure Error: ");
        Serial.println(err_buf);
        Serial.println(client.getWriteError());
    }
  }
  else {
...
```

The web server is however on my own network and I have created the SSL certificate for it.

I have created

- My own root certificate
- An intermediate certificate, signed by my    root CA
- A server certificate, signed by my intermediate CA

I change the Root CA in the aurdino example for mine, but I always get a SSL certificate error for the Root CA.  I have check all I can, including that the time is correct, but can't find the cause.

My output:

> Starting connection to server... Connection failed! Last
> WiFiClientSecure Error: X509 - Certificate verification failed, e.g.
> CRL, CA or signature check failed

In Postman, I load my certificate and I can execute it with no errors (Certificate shows as valid and OK).

I have tried the example with each of the certificates individually,and combinations of them in the example code, but all result in the same error.  (Of course I can set to insecure mode, but that defeats the purpose somewhat).

I suspect that there is something wrong with my Root CA, but I have tried many things and don't know what is wrong with it.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Please provide us with error code returned by lastError function, it will help us to identify the exact issue.

Comment: There is not any more information than what is shown above.  The method return "0", but that just indicates failure.